# Getting 'unknown symbol' error when using separate() in R

Tags: r, csv, tidyr

I have loaded a csv file into r called my_data. But some columns have multiple fields and I want to split them into separate new columns. When executing this command:

```
 separate(data=my_data,col=totals,into=c("Visits"  , "Hits", "Pageviews", 
"TransactionRevenue", "NewVisits"),sep=”,”)
```

I get this error message:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "separate(data=my_data,col=totals,into=c("Visits" , "Hits", "Pageviews", "TransactionRevenue”, "NewVisits"
```

I am trying to figure out what is wrong but with no success. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the sep= has smart quotes instead of straight quotes.  Try changing it to

```
separate(data=my_data,col=totals,into=c("Visits"  , "Hits", "Pageviews", 
"TransactionRevenue", "NewVisits"),sep=",")
```

Comment: Lesson: if you're going to write a blog post that contains code, don't use a word processor.